# What happens to ablative nozzles after a test fire?

Tags: engines, ablator

For example RS-68 engine

If you make a test fire of an ablative nozzle engine then the fire will consume the coating of that nozzle.

That means you have to replace the coating or the entire nozzle.

Are they replacing the coating after each test or they replace the entire nozzle?

Is the coating replaceable?

Comment: The other possibility is that there is enough ablator budgeted for both test fires and the real fire